# .net minimize ssl handshake data traffic

Tags: c#, ssl, x509certificate

I have a server application that uses TLS1.1 for authentication. Encryption is done with RSA-1.
The communication between this server and a windows client application works ok, but in the real world, the server application communicates with a small device that has limited memory.
It turns out that the initial handshake produces data packets that are too big for the device to handle (increasing the buffer size is not within my control), so my question is:

is it possible in .net to configure the ssl handshake process in more detail and if so, how? 
I am thinking of minimizing the list of distinguished names that the server sends to the client (during certificate request), which it uses to build the 'acceptableIssuers' list (without actually removing all the trusted CA certificates) or any other way to pinch a few bytes of the handshake process?
Thank you.

Comment: You know that you can disable sending the trused issuer list? See [MSKB - method 3](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/933430/en-us). Unfortunately this con only be configured system-wide.

Comment: I did not know about this registery setting. it helped reduce the size significantly (enough to overcome the buffer size limitations). thanks  On to the next problem with the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the first comment on the first post, change the registry setting to remove the list of distinguished names from the handshake:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL

[Method 3: Configure Schannel to no longer send the list of trusted root certificate authorities during the TLS/SSL handshake process](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/933430/en-us)

Answer (score 1):

The largest part are the certificates send by the server. To reduce this size:

- Send only the necessary certificates. Of course you need the leaf certificate (from the server).
- If you have any intermediate certificates try to install them as trusted at the client, so that you don't need to send them.
- And of course don't send the certificate of the root-CA, this should be at the client anyway.

If this is not enough you might need to get another certificate with a smaller key size, i.e. use 1024 bit but not 2048. 512 bit is too small for today and even with 1024 bit you might be in trouble in a few years.

Comment: all the 'distinguished names' of the installed trusted CA certificates are automatically send during the 'certificate request' stage of the handshake. With the registry setting as suggested in the comment on the first post, this list can be skipped, which significantly reduces the data that is sent during handshake.